# What does 'select processes without controlling ttys' mean?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, process

For the following command:

```
ps x
```

What does x achieve? The documentation specifies 'select processes without controlling ttys' but I don't understand what this means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some applications, such as interactive shells and TUI vim, run on terminals or terminal emulators. They "have a controlling tty". Other applications, such as daemons and graphical applications, do not.

Comment: so when I issue a ps x it's supposed to show all my process(?). Can you expand a little further please?

Comment: How much further can I expand than "doesn't hide processes that don't have a controlling terminal"?